# Set where Iron-Router renders templates by default

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I'm using iron-router, and by default this is attaching the template at the bottom of my  in the default layout file.

However, I would like to be able to specify this, but from the docs I can't quite work out how.

For example my html should look like this

```
<head>
<title>maecenas</title>
</head>

<body>
<div class="header">
    <div class="sitename">      
        <h1>Maecen.us</h1>
    </div>
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="{{pathFor 'about'}}">About</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                {{> loginButtons}}
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>
<content>
/*where I want it*/
</content>

</body>
```

How can I handle this?

Comment: I suggest reading http://www.manuel-schoebel.com/blog/iron-router-tutorial

Comment: Which is your layout template? Replace render stuff here with {{> yield}}

Comment: Added the layout template to post, in router I'm then doing render"somepage" and it appends at the bottom of body.

Answer (score 0):

Your layout specifies exactly where it should render the yield section. 
Take a close look at https://github.com/iron-meteor/iron-router/blob/devel/Guide.md#layouts

It has everything that you need to know.